# How to set the minimum required Windows?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I set the minimum required version of Windows with `$SETPEFLAG`? It can be done with 
`editbin.exe "$(TargetPath)" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 /OSVERSION:5.1` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set the minimum OS version using the `{$SetPeFlags}` directive.  You have to set it in the Project Options instead, on the [Linking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Linking) page:

> Project | Options | Delphi Compiler | Linking
>   Set OS Version fields in PE header as <major>.<minor>

The default is 5.0 (Windows 2000).

Comment: So I guess one project could be built for different versions at a time?

Comment: If you use multiple build configurations in the project, they can each have a different OS version specified.

Comment: Wow, default Windows 2000? Do people really still use that? You'd think it would at least be raised to XP.

Comment: @JerryDodge I still use Win2K on some old manufacturing systems.  They haven't been upgraded because of some old 16-bit hardware (ISA slot cards) - no drivers beyond Win2k.  I'll probably invest the time to upgrade them when our stock of spare parts starts to wear thin, but in the meantime, if it ain't broke...